# How to syntax highlight javascript and css in Visual studio 2013 PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, html, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013 I want to edit php files that include inline javascript and inline css.
However the image below shows my problem. In html files the javascript and css is syntax highlighted but in the php files the javascript and css is treated like plain text.

[image]

Is there a setting I can trigger to make the javascript and css be syntax highlighted in php files?

Comment: try to use  this  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8292e47d-8ed2-48cb-9ebd-064e0b7891cf  extention for visual studio